# How to match and replace img source with '../'

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove any number of '../' in image's source (src).

I have regular expression, which removes '../' and also works if there is no '../' in source.

```
<?php

$help_path = 'http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/';
$contents = <<<MYVAR
<img src="Links/WAS_PIC_ControlBox-1-2-3.jpg" alt="WAS-Betjeningsboks-1-2-3" 
style="border: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" border="0">

<img src="../Links/WAS_PIC_ControlBox-1-2-3.jpg" alt="WAS-Betjeningsboks-1-2-3" 
style="border: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" border="0">

<img src="../../Links/WAS_PIC_ControlBox-1-2-3.jpg" alt="WAS-Betjeningsboks-1-2-3" 
style="border: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" border="0">

<script type="text/javascript" src="ehlpdhtm.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../ehlpdhtm.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ehlpdhtm.js"></script>

MYVAR;

$find = array(
    '#<script\s+type="(.*?)"\s+src="(?:\.{2}/)?(.*?)">(.*?)</script>#is',
    '#<img\s+src="(?:\.{2}/)?(.*?)"\s+alt="(.*?)"([^>]*?)/?>#i'
);

$replace = array(
    '<script type="${1}" src="' . $help_path . '${2}"></script>',
    '<img src="' . $help_path . '${1}" alt="${2}"${3} />'
);

$preg_rep = preg_replace($find, $replace, $contents);
print_r($preg_rep);
```

Problem is that my regular expression outputs '../' if there's more than one '../' in src. It should always be like src="Links/xxx.jpg", no matter how many '../' are in source ('../../../../').

```
<img src="http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/Links/WAS_PIC_ControlBox-1-2-3.jpg" alt="WAS-Betjeningsboks-1-2-3" 
style="border: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" border="0" />

<img src="http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/Links/WAS_PIC_ControlBox-1-2-3.jpg" alt="WAS-Betjeningsboks-1-2-3" 
style="border: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" border="0" />

<img src="http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/../Links/WAS_PIC_ControlBox-1-2-3.jpg" alt="WAS-Betjeningsboks-1-2-3" 
style="border: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" border="0" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/ehlpdhtm.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/ehlpdhtm.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/../ehlpdhtm.js"></script>
```

Comment: Change `(?:\.{2}/)?` to `(?:\.{2}/)+` in your regex, so it removes not just one occurrence but more than one occurrence of it.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi that is not correct, it's ok if there's one or two '../', but it strps out part of URL, see example: https://www.tehplayground.com/pz8elKjipsCW5jqs

Comment: ok, I was actually already writing this that it is better to use `*` instead of `+` with `?` in your regex to allow matching of url in absence of `../` [Check this](https://www.tehplayground.com/ujd5F2COuyCbKYr7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` to remove all the ../

```
$contents = str_replace('../', '', $contents);
```

and after that, you can apply the regex

```
$contents = str_replace('../', '', $contents);
$find = array(
  '#<script\s+type="(.*?)"\s+src="(?:\.{2}/)?(.*?)">(.*?)</script>#is',
  '#<img\s+src="(?:\.{2}/)?(.*?)"\s+alt="(.*?)"([^>]*?)/?>#i'
);
$replace = array(
  '<script type="${1}" src="' . $help_path . '${2}"></script>',
  '<img src="' . $help_path . '${1}" alt="${2}"${3} />'
);

$preg_rep = preg_replace($find, $replace, $contents);
```